# Reading in an Excel file with pandas read Excel `invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '`

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas

I am reading in an Excel file with Python using pandas' function `read_excel`. However, I keep encountering the error `invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '` (full error, see below).

As I read the error, my understanding is that there is a single whitespace somewhere in a column where the other values of the column are integers. In order to fix this, I am trying to read in the Excel file without interpreting the cell values:

```
pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name = sheet_name, header = 0, converters = {colname : str for colname in colnames})
```

I have also tried this using:

```
pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name = sheet_name, header = 0, converters = {colname : object for colname in colnames})
```

and also replacing `converters` by `dtype`, but in all cases I keep getting the same error.. I just want to read in the Excel file such that I can look for data issues in Python.

I also find it strange that when I type

```
pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name = sheet_name, usecols = "A")
```

where the column `A` doesn't contain integers, I still have the same error.

Full error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
ValueError                                
Traceback (most recent call last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11216/3112089226.py in <module>
----> 1 pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name = "Forecasted Flights (6 months)", header = 0, converters = {colname : str for colname in colnames})

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    309                     stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310                 )
--> 311             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    312 
    313         return wrapper

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in read_excel(io, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols, storage_options)
    370 
    371     try:
--> 372         data = io.parse(
    373             sheet_name=sheet_name,
    374             header=header,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in parse(self, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols, **kwds)    1270             DataFrame from the passed in Excel file.    1271         """
-> 1272         return self._reader.parse(    1273             sheet_name=sheet_name,    1274             header=header,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in parse(self, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, dtype, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, verbose, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols, **kwds)
    537                 sheet = self.get_sheet_by_index(asheetname)
    538 
--> 539             data = self.get_sheet_data(sheet, convert_float)
    540             if hasattr(sheet, "close"):
    541                 # pyxlsb opens two TemporaryFiles

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py in get_sheet_data(self, sheet, convert_float)
    570         data: list[list[Scalar]] = []
    571         last_row_with_data = -1
--> 572         for row_number, row in enumerate(sheet.rows):
    573             converted_row = [self._convert_cell(cell, convert_float) for cell in row]
    574             while converted_row and converted_row[-1] == "":

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_read_only.py in
_cells_by_row(self, min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row, values_only)
     77                                  data_only=self.parent.data_only, epoch=self.parent.epoch,
     78                                  date_formats=self.parent._date_formats)
---> 79         for idx, row in parser.parse():
     80             if max_row is not None and idx > max_row:
     81                 break

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py in parse(self)
    153                 element.clear()
    154             elif tag_name == ROW_TAG:
--> 155                 row = self.parse_row(element)
    156                 element.clear()
    157                 yield row

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py in parse_row(self, row)
    284             self.row_dimensions[str(self.row_counter)] = attrs
    285 
--> 286         cells = [self.parse_cell(el) for el in row]
    287         return self.row_counter, cells
    288 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    284             self.row_dimensions[str(self.row_counter)] = attrs
    285 
--> 286         cells = [self.parse_cell(el) for el in row]
    287         return self.row_counter, cells
    288 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py in parse_cell(self, element)
    200         elif value is not None:
    201             if data_type == 'n':
--> 202                 value = _cast_number(value)
    203                 if style_id in self.date_formats:
    204                     data_type = 'd'

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py in
_cast_number(value)
     80     if "." in value or "E" in value or "e" in value:
     81         return float(value)
---> 82     return int(value)
     83 
     84 

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '
```

Answer (score 0):

Your attempts so far have not worked because they do not handle this special case of `' '`. You can make this fix during or after import. For example, you can make use of the `converters` a write a special function just for this problem column that otherwise contains `int`. Here is just one possible function, written as a `lambda` function so you can place it in-line with the [`read_excel(...)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas-read-excel) call:

```
lambda strVal: 0 if strVal in ['', ' '] else int(strVal)
```

You could also replace the problem value `' '` with `NaN` using the `na_values` option, though this would change the dtype to `float`.

Comment: Do you mean writing the below code? This gives me the same error (here int_colnames are all columns with integer values).
|



pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name = sheet_name, header = 0, converters = {colname : lambda strVal: (0 if strVal in ['', ' '] else int(strVal)) for colname in int_colnames})